# android: Replace the checkbox in CheckedTextView by an button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

By default, there is a checkedbox in CheckedTextView, but now I want to replace it by an button.
I have tried to **setCheckMarkDrawable** which does exactly what I want it look like.

But now the problem is how can I add a listener to this. I want this button to remove current item in the ListView. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your button by calling a ressource id like that:

```
setCheckMarkDrawable (R.id.myListButton);
```

Then set your listener on that button with:

```
(Button)findViewById(R.id.myListButton)
.setOnclickListener(new onClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v) 
        {
        //Do somethting here
        }
});
```